# Contour integration and wolfram

Tags: integration, wolfram-alpha

I am not sure if this is the right site to ask this question, but here it is:

Does Wolfram Alpha do contour integrals? If so how might I access that feature. Also, is there an online manual for Wolfram?

Many thanks.

Comment: You may want to ask the question here. (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you parameterize the contour then it should be possible.  Did you have a specific integral in mind?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Not really but say I want to integrate z along the unit circle, what should I type in?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Ah I see how it works now, thanks! Nonetheless, is there some sort of manual available for WA?

Comment: @user17762 I am not supposed to ask a question like this here maybe, but I don't know another place to get the answer. I want Wolfram to calculate an inegral of $\frac{alnx}{b+x}$ but I don't know what to type in the box where I ask the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are two ways the integral 
$$\int_C \frac{d z}{z},$$
where $C$ is the unit circle traversed counterclockwise, can be handled:

(1) [using the definition of a complex line integral;](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20exp%28-i%20f%29%20i%20exp%28i%20f%29%20df%20from%20f=0%20to%202pi)

(2) [using the residue theorem.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=residue%20of%20%282%20Pi%20I%29%2a1/z%20at%20z=0)

I have found all I need to know about Wolfram Alpha [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/). 
Here are some pages relevant to [contour](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Calculus.html) [integration](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/ComplexAnalysis.html).

Comment: Wolfram Alpha [does not follow](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=1%2Fe%3D1%2F%282+pi+i%29+Nintegrate%5Bgamma%28s%29%28-%28-1%29%29%5E-s%2C%7Bs%2C-1%2F2-sqrt%28-1%29+infty%2C-1%2F2%2Bsqrt%28-1%29+infty%7D%5D) the [contour integral for $e^z$](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Exp/07/01/0002/) or is there rule for the input WolframAlpha needs to evaluate integrals with complex number bounds?

Comment: @TymaGaidash: I would try something like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=%7B1%2FE%2C1%2F%282+pi+I%29+NIntegrate%5BGamma%281%2BI+t%29I%2C%7Bt%2C-infty%2Cinfty%7D%5D%7D%2F%2FN).